# La sévérité de l'usage incorrect de l'imparfait vs le passé composé

Tags: usage, temps-grammatical, oral, passé-composé, imparfait

Je dois avouer que de temps en temps j'ai toujours des difficultés en choisissant le temps correct entre l'imparfait et le passé composé. Je voudrais savoir quelle est la sévérité de l'emploi du mauvais temps en face d'une autre personne. Il n'y a souvent pas assez de temps pour s'arrêter, y penser, et utiliser le temps correct. Je me rends compte qu'un usage incorrect ne vas probablement pas causer beaucoup de confusion, mais est-ce que ça frappera un peu l'autre personne comme un usage incorrect de genre ?

Lié: j'ai remarqué qu'il y a parfois des désaccords entre membres sur ce forum (et quelques autres) concernant l'emploi de l'un ou l'autre. Ça m'indique qu'un usage incorrect de ces deux temps arrive assez fréquemment (ou, au moins, de temps en temps) parmi les locuteurs natifs eux-mêmes. Est-ce que c'est vrai ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans la plupart des cas, une confusion entre l'imparfait et le passé composé se remarque et perturbe assez le sens de la phrase et l'interlocuteur. Je distingue un cas où le passé composé utilisé à la place de l'imparfait n'est pas si choquant *à l'oral* : le passé lointain à action continue. Exemples :

> Quand j'étais petit, je faisais du vélo.
> Quand j'étais petit, j'ai fait du vélo.
>
> Durant ma jeunesse, je faisais les quatre-cents coups.
> Durant ma jeunesse, j'ai fait les quatre-cents coups.
>
> Il y a quelques années, je travaillais mes abdos. Aujourd'hui, j'ai arrêté.
> Il y a quelques années, j'ai travaillé mes abdos. Aujourd'hui, j'ai arrêté.

Ces constructions au passé composé ne me choquent pas à l'oral, même si l'imparfait reste préférable.

Comment: La dernière phrase me choque. Pour les autres il y a une légère nuance de sens.

Comment: Maintenant que je la vois, effectivement il y a un problème. C'est dû au "Avant". Je remplace par "Il y a quelques années".

Comment: Je ne connaissais pas la nuance de sens entre les 2 constructions, pouvez-vous expliquer ?

Comment: La première construction décrit une habitude ou s'utilise dans le cadre d'une narration, alors que la deuxième décrit une expérience. Compare « j'ai déjà fait du vélo quand j'étais petit » à « je faisais déjà du vélo quand j'étais petit », la nuance de sens apparait plus facilement : le *déjà* s'accroche au présent dans la première phrase, et au passé dans la seconde.

Comment: La phrase "J'ai eu 5 ans" vous choquerait-elle ? J'ai *maintenant* l'intuition de savoir que je devrais employer l'imparfait, mais il n'existe pas une bonne raison pour ça dans ma tête. Elle me semble nuancée. Sur une main, il y a une durée précise quand j'avais 5 ans. Cette durée a commencé et s'est arrêtée - elle est finie. C'est évident qu'elle est complète, qu'elle s'est passée une seul fois, et elle continue non plus. Cependant sur l'autre main, la phrase pourrait être une partie d'une narration ou décrire un état. À mon avis, il y a de bonne raisons d'employer tous les deux temps.

Comment: Bref, est-ce qu'une personne qui parle français comme leur langue maternelle sent cette nuance ?

Comment: @bronxbomber92 N.B. : En lieu et place de *sur une main ... sur l'autre main* utiliser l'idiome *d'un coté ..., de l'autre...*

Comment: @bronxbomber92 « J’ai eu cinq ans » n’est pas choquant, mais il mets l’accent sur le fait que ton anniversaire a eu lieu, ou sur le fait qu’un jour, tu as eu cinq ans, pas sur le laps de temps pendant lequel tu avais cinq ans. « Qu’as-tu fait ces vacances ? — J’ai eu cinq ans ! — Bon anniversaire ! »; « Moi aussi, j’ai eu cinq ans. » peut signifier que tu sais ce que c’est que d’avoir cinq ans car tu te souviens de cet âge-là. « J’avais cinq ans quand ma petite sœur est née » signifie « Pendant l’année de mes cinq ans, ma petite sœur est née ».

Comment: @bronxbomber92 Et, oui, la nuance se ressent chez le locuteur natif (même si, dans le second exemple, je privilégie personnellement le passé composé). Mais, en pratique, l’interprétation se déduit également du contexte. En pratique, je doute que quiconque te reproche un mauvais emploi au quotidien.

Comment: Merci @Édouard ! Avec ces commentaires supplémentaires, je vais marquer ce réponse comme "répondu".

Answer (score 3):

Un habitant de Savoie vous répond. Mais avec une façon de parler populaire. Alors pour répondre, durant mes discussions avec les gens qui m'environnent, il me semble bien que le plus souvent les temps ne sont pas mélangés. On utilise le passé composé pour des actions effectuées dans un passé proche, par exemple :

> la semaine dernière, j'ai fait du canoë [le langage que j'utilise nativement serait : 'la s'maine dernière, j'suis parti faire du canoë'].

Alors que j'utilise l'imparfait quand je dis par exemple :

> Je faisais du canoë quand j'étais petit [ce qui est une époque révolue].

Donc pour répondre à votre message, dans la région où je vis, ou alors parmi les gens qui m'entourent, les erreurs de temps comme vous l'indiquez sont fausses. Mais la langue française étant parlée différemment d'une région à une autre, je ne peux en faire une généralité.

Answer (score 1):

Intuitivement :

> *Autrefois,.. je faisais ..* induit *.. et c'était le bon temps*,

C'est la notion du passé, du merveilleux passé de l'enfance, ou les périodes heureuses de notre jeunesse que l'on regrette devant la dure réalité de l'adulte *(dans le temps c'était bien, maintenant ...)*
alors que

> *Autrefois, .. j'ai fait ...* sous-entend *et maintenant je ne le peux plus*

par ce que l'on a en tête les dictons liés à *ce qui est fait*:

> "Ce qui est est fait, est fait" :  on ne peut plus revenir en arrière, on ne peut plus modifier les conséquences de l'action
>   "Ce qui est fait n'est plus à faire." : le contraire de la procrastination, on se débarrasse de ce qui nous ennuie, et l'on va enfin faire ce qui nous plaît.

---

Il y a moins de désaccords réels que de points de vue différents :

- D'un coté celui des grammairiens, qui répondent d'abord avec leur mental, leurs savoirs, leurs certitudes pour approcher la rigueur et la complexité du langage écrit.
- De l'autre celui des littéraires, plus ou moins artistes, qui proposent des réponses basées sur leur intuition, leur sensibilité, qu'ils référencent dans l'oralité, pour essayer d'être des passeurs de mots chargés de toutes leurs nuances.

Bien sûr chacun porte ces deux types en soi, et un équilibre s'effectue, comme dans le *[yin yang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XJlE.gif)* pour régler le problème de la lettre et de l'esprit, le problème des mots [leur définition] et du sens des mots [les différents niveaux de compréhension].
Il ne suffit pas d'avoir un dictionnaire et une grammaire pour parler une langue ; s'ils sont nécessaires, ils ne sont pas suffisants.

Comment: « *Ce qui est fait* » ce n'est pas un bon exemple, syntaxiquement c'est du présent (dans une tournure passive), au passé composé ça donne « *ce qui a été fait* »…

Comment: Ce n'est pas le temps de la conjugaison qui  résonne à l'oreille, mais une sorte d'homophonie : *je fais* ou *j'ai fait* ne demandent pas la même articulation que *je faisais* ; *je fais* --> maintenant, *j'ai fait* --> c'est passé ; *je* et *j'ai* sont proches à l'oreille, il y a une sorte d'amalgame qui les rapproche instinctivement. Comme je l'ai mis en exergue, c'est ce que je ressens intuitivement pour tenter d'expliquer un usage. Je l'avoue, c'est plus proche du yin littéraire que du yang lumineux des grammairien :)