# Substituer « que » par « comme » ou « c'est que » par « cela ressemble » ?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions

Dans son dernier commentaire [à cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/7577/1995), l'utilisateur Édouard a écrit :

> […] peut signifier *que tu sais ce que c’est **que** d’avoir* cinq ans car tu te souviens de cet âge-là.

Il me semble qu'une structure analogue figure dans [*Mystères de l'Inquisition et autres sociétés secrètes d'Espagne* de  M. V. de Féréal](http://books.google.com/books?id=IkxbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA179&dq=%22qu%27ils+savent+ce+que+c%27est+que+d%27avoir%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=u2dmUrXZL8e7iAfYi4GIAg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22qu%27ils%20savent%20ce%20que%20c%27est%20que%20d%27avoir%22&f=false) :

> — Pauvre insensée ! dit José d'une voix amère en regardant Juana, qui pleurait ; est-ce que les inquisiteurs ont une âme ? est-ce *qu'ils savent ce que c'est **que** d'avoir* un père, une mère, une amante ou une sœur ? Jamais un sentiment a-t-il fait tressaillir leurs entrailles de marbre ? Connaissent-ils donc d'autres sensations que les désirs lascifs, féroces et impitoyables; les délires monstrueux d'une débauche effrénée, la soif du sang, le spectacle de l'agonie ?

Je comprends que la structure telle quelle est : *... + que + sujet + verbe + ce que + c'est + **que** + de + verbe ...* Toutefois, pourquoi **que**, plutôt que **comme** ou **cela ressemble** ? Pourquoi pas,

> Est-ce *qu'ils savent ce que c'est **comme** d'avoir* un père…
>
> ou Est-ce *qu'ils savent ce que **cela ressemble** d'avoir* un père… ?

Answer (score 4):

Aucune de ces deux substitutions (*comme* ou *cela ressemble*) n'est correcte. On pourra au choix

- éliminer le *que* : *ils savent ce que c'est d'avoir un père*
- monter des tournures un peu plus compliquées : *ils savent à quoi ça ressemble d'avoir un père*, *ils savent ce que ça fait d'avoir un père*, etc.

Comment: Je ne sais sur quel pied danser pour la première suggestion. Par contre j’ajouterais « Ils savent ce qu’est avoir un père ».

Comment: "Par contre" ? Ce n'est que l'abréviation de "par-contre envoi" (on dit maintenant "par retour de courrier"), pas un substitut de "en revanche".

Comment: En l’occurrence, je ne veux pas exprimer « en revanche », je veux exprimer « [par contre](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/contre) ».

Comment: Pourquoi pas "mais", "cependant", "toutefois", "néanmoins", etc. ?

Comment: @Édouard: Pourriez-vous expliciter comment et pourquoi les 2 tentatives ladites sont erronées ?

Answer (score 0):

**"Que" est un mot redoutable en français.**

1- Il peut être **conjonction**, introduisant *une subordonnée* :

a) sujet : "Il m'est indifférent qu'il ait du succès" ;

b) objet : "Je crois qu'il a du succès" ;

c) circonstanciel : "Je croyais être enfin bon, qu'il m'a dépassé" [temps] ; "Il est si fort, que je tremble devant lui" [cause] ; "Venez, que je vous félicite" [but] ; "Il en fut si ému qu'il trembla" [conséquence] ; "Que ma lettre soit appréciée, cela me surprendrait" [hypothèse].

Ou introduisant une *proposition indépendante* :

"Je souhaite que ce soit permis".

Ou *purement coordinative*, et analogue à "comme", "puisque", etc..

"Il en est ainsi, que je le veuille ou non".

Et enfin se combine avec "plus", "moins", "tel", etc..

2- Il peut être **adverbe**, interrogatif ou exclamatif :

"Que me dites-vous là  *?*  ou *!* "

3- Il peut enfin être **pronom relatif**, ou **pronom interrogatif ou exclamatif**, représentant un sujet, objet, ou complément circonstanciel :

"Je sais ce que je veux" ; "C'est à vous que ces discours s'adressent" ; "Que seriez-vous sans lui !" ; "Que se passe-t-il ?".

Pour répondre enfin à la question, il semble que trois tournures soient également bonnes, mais de styles différents :

"Ils savent ce que c'est, d'avoir un père". [simple]

"Ils savent ce que c'est, que d'avoir un père". [plus insistant]

"Ils savent ce que c'est que d'avoir un père". [plus éloquent]

Comment: En quoi cela répond-il à la question?