# passé et devoir

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical, mode-grammatical, auxiliaires

J'ai certaines questions concernant l'emploi du verbe devoir au passé :

> 1. Il a dû partir.
> 2. Il devait partir.
> 3. Il dut partir.
> 4. Il aurait du partir.

- Quand faut-il employer chacun temps ?
- Quelles différences existent entre 1 et 3 dans le français courant et dans le français plus littéraire ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Il a d**û** partir.

1. Il **est parti** car il n'avait pas le choix.
2. Il est probablement parti (car on ne le trouve pas).

> Il devai**t** partir.

Quelque chose d'autre s'est passé avant le départ qui l'a interrompu ou retardé.

> Il dut partir.

Il **partit** car n'avait pas le choix (littéraire).

> Il aurait du partir.

Il n'est pas parti alors que c'était prévu ou que c'était la bonne décision.

Comment: @jiliagre Merci. Donc, λε Passe Composé a plus de sens que λε Passé Simple. Ce ne sont pas totalement interchangeables.

Comment: Ils sont d'autant moins interchangeables que le passé simple ne s'emploie plus à l'oral, en dehors d'effets de style. À l'écrit, il peut y avoir des nuances. Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/9/diff%C3%A9rence-entre-le-pass%C3%A9-simple-et-le-pass%C3%A9-compos%C3%A9

Comment: C'est noté ! Merci encore car tu as mis au premier plan les questions https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7549/la-s%C3%A9v%C3%A9rit%C3%A9-de-lusage-incorrect-de-limparfait-vs-le-pass%C3%A9-compos%C3%A9 et https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/6249/imparfait-vs-pass%C3%A9-compos%C3%A9-for-devoir